# Datatable fixed left column (rank)

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using datatables to display hockey players statistics.

The first column is simply the rank from 1 to 100 of the player in that row.

When I order by goals or assists or whatever column I select, I want that first column to remain fixed (since that column only indicates the players' rank for the sort).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on Datatables' website:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html